# Pycharm collapse list when writing to text file

Tags: python, pycharm, fwrite

I am using PyCharm ide!!

I have a function that writes a list and some lines to a text file and it seems no problem with it. The function is below:

```
    def write_model_to_disk(self):

        self.assign_transition_to_model()

        with open("generated_model/partitioned_model.prism", "w+") as f:
            f.write("dtmc" "\n")
            for list_item in GeneratedModel.result_parameter:
                f.write(list_item)
            f.write("module main" "\n")
            # f.write("s:[0.." % event_log.get_states_no(event_log_data) % "]" % "init" % "0" % "\n")
            f.writelines(["s:[0.." + str(Logfile.no_of_states) + "]" + " " + "init" + " " + "0" + ";" + "\n"])
            for list_item in GeneratedModel.result_transitions:
                f.write(list_item)
            f.write("endmodule" "\n")
```

My problem is that when the functions write the text the list gets collapsed/folded like this:

[This How the text gets writen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L73tt.png)

And when I click the arrow at the left I get the following:

[After I clicked the arrow at the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZH8GF.png)

When I opened the text file using finder I got this:
[Using text file editor to open from finder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX9he.png)

So, I don't if my problem is related to Pycharm or my function.

Comment: I suggest replacing `f.write(list_item)` with `f.write(list_item+"\n")` …

Comment: I did the changes you suggested but unfortunately, it did not solve it. Thanks for your effort.